# Collect items from multiple requests in an array in Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I wrote a small example spider to illustrate my problem:

```py
class ListEntrySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = ['https://example.com/lists']

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in json.dumps(response.text)['ids']:
           scrapy.Request(f'https://example.com/list/{i}', callback=self.parse_lists)

    def parse_lists(self, response):
        for entry in json.dumps(response.text)['list']:
            yield ListEntryItem(**entry)
```

I need to have all the items that result from multiple requests (all `ListEntryItem`s in an array inside the spider, so dispatch requests that depend on **all** items.

My first idea was to chain the requests and pass the remaining IDs and the already extracted items in the request's meta attribute until the last request is reached.

```py
class ListEntrySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = ['https://example.com/lists']

    def parse(self, response):
        ids = json.dumps(response.text)['ids']
        yield self._create_request(ids, [])

    def parse_lists(self, response):
        self._create_request(response.meta['ids'], response.meta['items'].extend(list(self._extract_lists(response))))

    def finish(self, response):
        items = response.meta['items'].extend(list(self._extract_lists(response)))

    def _extract_lists(self, response):
        for entry in json.dumps(response.text)['list']:
            yield ListEntryItem(**entry)

    def _create_request(self, ids: list, items: List[ListEntryItem]):
        i = ids.pop(0)
        return scrapy.Request(
            f'https://example.com/list/{i}',
            meta={'ids': ids, 'items': items},
            callback=self.parse_lists if len(ids) > 1 else self.finish
        )
```

As you can see, my solution looks very complex. I'm looking for something more readable and less complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are different approaches for this. One is chaining as you do. Problems occur is one of the requests in the middle of the chain is dropped for any reason. Your have to be really careful about that and handle all possible errors / ignored requests.

Another approach is to use a separate spider for all "grouped" requests.
You can start those spiders programmatically and pass a bucket (e.g. a dict) as spider attribute. Within your pipeline you add your items from each request to this bucket. From "outside" you listen to the spider_closed signal and get this bucket which then contains all your items.

Look here for how to start a spider programatically via a crawler runner:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process

pass a bucket to your spider when calling crawl() of your crawler runner
`crawler_runner_object.crawl(YourSpider, bucket=dict())`

and catch the sider_closed signal

```
from scrapy.signalmanager import dispatcher

def on_spider_closed(spider):
    bucket = spider.bucket

dispatcher.connect(on_spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
```

this approach might seem even more complicated than chaining your requests but it actually takes a lot of complexity out of the problem as within your spider you can make your requests without taking much care about all the other requests.